# Prompt for Setup on First Boot

Tags: installation, boot, partitioning, live-usb, live-environment

I would like to have Ubuntu set its self up when it boots, as Windows does. There is a laptop that I am giving to a kid on Christmas with a dead Hard Drive, and I would like to prepare it for him. The laptop is not currently in my possession, but the hard drive is. I can do the troubleshooting for him if drivers are necessary later, but I would like the Hard Drive to have Ubuntu installed on it and just needing configuration with users and passwords. I have seen something like what I want before, but it was by a wubi install, and it did not prompt for a username and password to create.

So, if that confused you, my goal is to have the computer when it boots to prompt for a username and password to create.

I have an idea that could work, but not as well as desired. Currently, I have a live CD of Ubuntu 13.10, and I was planning on putting the Hard Drive in my laptop as its only, booting from a live usb, wiping the Hard Drive, creating a 512 Mb partition leaving the rest blank, and burning a live CD to that Hard drive to boot from. So, I would want to tweak the live HD's install to not allow the option for try Ubuntu.

I would prefer this to be on 13.10 because I have been using it flawlessly for the past month or two, and it has many features he would like. I am ok if it is only possible on 12.04.

So, to present all my Questions

- Can I install Ubuntu without a user, but prompt for one on First boot
- Or, can I install Ubuntu from a Hard Drive as a live CD to itself

If one of them gets answered, but not the other please answer the other one if you can for anyone else looking at this post. I will be trying the second method tonight possibly and answer below.

Comment: not quite sure what your asking in the last part of your question, but you can place the HD in another computer, then install viz the OEM install as stated in Angels answer below, just install any needed programs as instructed by the link he provided and then finalize the install.  The only issue may be that if the laptop has Nvidia or ATI graphic cards and the computer you use does not, it will be difficult to install the correct drivers.  After the install is "ready to ship" you can just install it into the laptop, but obviously, don't boot the laptop up.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is an OEM install.

See [Ubuntu OEM Installer Overview](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview) in the Community Wiki.

Comment: +1, just a note, the link states that you need to hold shift to get to the menu....you can just press any key once you see the "little man and keyboard" icon show at the bottom of the screen to get the menu up as well.